# Is there a way to encrypt data on a smart contract in a secure way?

Tags: contract-development, smart-contract-wallets, smart-lock

Is there a way to encrypt data on a smart contract in a secure way?

For instance - I have a smart lock that at any point I want only one user to open.
So I thought maybe a smart contract will check if you're the current owner and if you're it will encrypt your data and provide a valid signature.

is such a scenario is possible by any chance?

Comment: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/tree/master/contracts/utils/cryptography

Comment: Everything on the blockchain is public and anyone can read it, so the only option is to do the encryption off-chain.